# Solve the integral: $ \iint_D (x^2 \tan(x) + y^3 + 4) dxdy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Solve the following integral

$$ \iint_{D} (x^2 \tan(x) + y^3 + 4)dxdy$$

where $D = \{ (x,y): x^2 + y^2 \leq 2\}$

I thought that a polar coordinates transformation would work but it takes an horrible form. Any suggestion to solve it?
Thanks!

Comment: Mathematica gives the answer as $8\pi$ using rectangular coordinates. I suppose it would work in rectangular coordinate.

Comment: you mean using $xy$ coordinates? I couldnt solve it as well

Comment: The hard part is $x^2 \tan(x)$ ... rest is easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being odd function, 
$$\int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt 2 } \int_{-\sqrt{2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}} x^2 \tan(x) \, dydx = \int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt 2 } \int_{-\sqrt{2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{2-y^2}} x^2 \tan(x) \, dxdy = 0$$
rest is easy.

EDIT:: the integral consist of three parts. The first part which I showed above is zero by symmetry of bounds for odd function.
$$\iint_{D} (x^2 \tan(x) + y^3 + 4)dxdy$$

The second part is also zero since it is odd function of $y$
$$\int_D y^3 \, dx dy = \int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt 2 } \int_{-\sqrt{2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}} y^3 \, dy dx = 0$$

The third part is 
$$\int_D 4 \, dx dy = 4 \int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt 2 } \int_{-\sqrt{2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}} 1 \, dx dy = 4  \cdot \pi 2 = 8 \pi $$

The answer is $8 \pi $ you can check it [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Bx%5E2+Tan%5Bx%5D+%2B+y%5E3+%2B+4%2C+%7Bx%2C+-Sqrt%5B2%5D%2C+Sqrt%5B2%5D%7D%2C%7By%2C+-Sqrt%5B2+-x%5E2%5D%2C+Sqrt%5B2+-+x%5E2%5D%7D%5D).

Comment: I dont see how to solve this integrals

Comment: @Giiovanna okay i'll update answer in few min.

Comment: @Giiovanna okay I updated let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: I told you that I don't know how to solve the first integral (the integral with $x^2 \tan(x)$)

Comment: @Giiovanna you don't need to solve, I don't know if I can solve or not ... but I know for sure it's zero, because for odd function $f(x)$, 
$$\int_{-a}^{a}f(x) dx = 0$$

Comment: Oh, ok. I didn't know that. Thanks

Comment: @Giiovanna also probably your professor wants that way, the indefinite integral does not appear to have any [closed form](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Bx%5E2+Tan%5Bx%5D%2C+x%5D)

Comment: Yep, I've found that it cannot be expressed and a sum of elementary functions. Since I had forget this theorem about odd functions, I couldn't solve it